# Showing related items to the same model on detail page

Tags: python, django, select, model, django-select-related

I'm working on the News model. I have a list page and a detail page.
I need on the detail page with the option of selecting other related news in the admin panel and saving them on the site.

My model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    link = models.ForeignKey('.'.join(LINK_MODEL), null=True, blank=True)
    link_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    image = FilerImageField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'news'
        ordering = ['-date']
```

Should I use a foreign key?

Comment: Use foreign key

Comment: @marin like this: `related_news = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: Keep in mind using that `on_delete` will delete your `related_news` items when the parent object is deleted too.